# Error in setting up Twig with CodeIgniter

Tags: twig, codeigniter-3

I am trying to set up Twig Templating Engine with my new Codeigniter project.

But I am getting this error after setting up

```
Twig Exception

    There are no registered paths for namespace "__main__".
```

I don't know what this error means. and how to solve it.

As per I am checking this is originated from the following file-

```
/application/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:
```

code:

```
    class Twig_Loader_Filesystem implements Twig_LoaderInterface, Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface, Twig_SourceContextLoaderInterface
    {
        /** Identifier of the main namespace. */
        const MAIN_NAMESPACE = '__main__';

        protected $paths = array();
        protected $cache = array();
        protected $errorCache = array();

        private $rootPath;

        ...
```

I followed this article for setting up

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Twig-PHP-Template-Engine-Implementation

Codeigniter Version- 3.1.8

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it.

I was missing this entry in autoload.php file

```
$autoload['config'] = array('twig');
```